# Boxplots of grouped data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create some boxplots of grouped data using python's pandas library. The output should be one boxplot for each sex and pclass, 6 in total. My code is as follow:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Age":[34,12,78,84,26,30], 
                   "Sex":['Male','Female', 'Male','Female', 'Male','Female'], 
                   "Pclass":[1,1,2,2,3,3], 
                   "Survived":[0,0,0,1,1,1]})

df.groupby(['Sex','Pclass']).boxplot(column='Age', by='Survived')
```

But I am getting a error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4241a9c73bb3> in <module>()
      6                    "Survived":[0,0,0,1,1,1]})
      7 
----> 8 df.groupby(['Sex','Pclass']).boxplot(column='Age', by='Survived')

/home/leokury/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.pyc in boxplot_frame_groupby(grouped, subplots, column, fontsize, rot, grid, ax, figsize, layout, **kwds)
   3110                               rot=rot, grid=grid, **kwds)
   3111             ax.set_title(pprint_thing(key))
-> 3112             ret.loc[key] = d
   3113         fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15, top=0.9, left=0.1,
   3114                             right=0.9, wspace=0.2)

/home/leokury/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    138         else:
    139             key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 140         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
    141         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    142 

/home/leokury/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in _get_setitem_indexer(self, key)
    125 
    126         try:
--> 127             return self._convert_to_indexer(key, is_setter=True)
    128         except TypeError as e:
    129 

/home/leokury/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1228                 mask = check == -1
   1229                 if mask.any():
-> 1230                     raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
   1231 
   1232                 return _values_from_object(indexer)

KeyError: "['Female' 1] not in index"
```

Is this a bug or I made something wrong?

My pd.show_versions() output:

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.12.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 4.4.0-57-generic
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: pt_BR.UTF-8
LOCALE: pt_BR.UTF-8

pandas: 0.19.2+0.g825876c.dirty
nose: 1.3.7
pip: 8.1.2
setuptools: 23.0.0
Cython: 0.24
numpy: 1.11.1
scipy: 0.17.1
statsmodels: 0.6.1
xarray: None
IPython: 4.2.0
sphinx: 1.4.1
patsy: 0.4.1
dateutil: 2.5.3
pytz: 2016.4
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.1.0
tables: 3.2.2
numexpr: 2.6.0
matplotlib: 1.5.1
openpyxl: 2.3.2
xlrd: 1.0.0
xlwt: 1.1.2
xlsxwriter: 0.9.2
lxml: 3.6.0
bs4: 4.4.1
html5lib: None
httplib2: None
apiclient: None
sqlalchemy: 1.0.13
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.8
boto: 2.40.0
pandas_datareader: None
```

Comment: I think it's b/c you have only one row per each unique groupby identifier, so can't do a boxplot on a single row.  (obviously that's not easy to get from the error message).  For example, it works for me if I remove 'pclass' from the groupby:  `df.groupby(['Sex']).boxplot(column='Age', by='Survived')`

Comment: I don't think so. Even if I use the full dataset with more than 800 records I get the same error.

https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/download/train.csv

Comment: Check capitalization.  I just ran on Titanic dataset (not from kaggle tho).  It crashed with similar error until I changed from "Sex" to "sex" and similar for other variables.  Also try doing a mean() instead of boxplot() on the groupby to further trouble shoot this.

Comment: Using mean() it is ok but with boxplot not.. Is this a bug?

I checked capitalization but even using all lower case I still get error.